# Reverting splitted commits

Tags: git

I have to revert multiple commits (pushed) in between different commits (pushed). Actually what happened is while working on a project I always did `git pull` instead of `git pull --rebase`, so my commits went in between commits from another person and I pushed it too. Now I want to revert inbetween (pushed) commits of mine from the branch.

For example:

```
A-B-C-D-E-F-G-H
```

I want to revert `C`, `E` and `G` without affecting the remaining commits.

Is there a way around considering I can't delete the current branch while fixing this?

Comment: what is wrong with running `git revert <commit-hash>` for C, E, G (one by one)?

Comment: If you just want to get rid of those revisions as if they had never happened on branch history:
```git checkout B; git cherry-pick D; git cherry-pick F; git cherry-pick G```. You are creating a whole new branch history, just in case.

Comment: @IgorSoloydenko it is causing conflicts to happen(like - 'deleted by us, and modified) I resolved those conflicts and somehow reverted them but after revert the files I am left with are having conflict blocks in them.

Comment: @Edmundo ya I thought of that but I can have only one branch with that name for eg - branch1 and I can't loose this name for my project. so If I go by this approach I have delete the current branch and create a whole new branch with same name. Any other solution you can suggest of ?

Comment: @Bruce_Wayne see the answer below. There's no royal path when we hit conflicts. They have to be resolved.

Comment: Honestly it seems to me that fixing up the branch names at the end is the least of the problems here...

Comment: It is possible to run git revert C E G as one command. Then you can use git revert --continue as you resolve conflicts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Option 1

This should do the job:

```
git revert <commit-hash-of-G>
git revert <commit-hash-of-E>
git revert <commit-hash-of-C>
```

The only drawback is that this will *create* new commits. **This is a way to go, if you shared the branch (pushed to remote) already**.

## Option 2

**Otherwise**, you can use @Edmundo's suggestion:

- create a new branch from the right parent commit

by

```
 git checkout <commit-hash-of-A>
 git checkout -b repaired-branch
```

- cherry pick the good commits only

by

```
git cherry-pick <commit-hash-of-B>
git cherry-pick <commit-hash-of-D>
git cherry-pick <commit-hash-of-F>
git cherry-pick <commit-hash-of-G>
```

Comment: As a matter of fact, if you are reverting, you should revert them in reverse order from the latest to the oldest (unless the content of the 3 revisions you are reverting is unrelated).

Comment: @Edmundo You are right, I have made a broad assumption. Corrected my answer

Answer (score 1):

Other answers give you good basic information, but a few details should be filled in:

First, you say "revert the commit", which (particularly in git) just means "make the current state look as it would without the commit".  The `git revert` command doesn't change the history, so you would see in the log (newest to oldest)

```
Revert C
Revert E
Revert G
H
G
F
E
D
C
B
A
```

My reading of your question is that you want to remove `C`, `E`, and `G` from the history (perhaps with intent to reintroduce those changes via a feature branch, or a squashed commit, or other way).

Because everything has been pushed, there is no "good" way to do that.  Any change to history will require everyone who has a clone of the repo to perform a recovery procedure.  The `git rebase` documentation spells this out when it talks about "recovering from an upstream rebase", but it applies to *any* operation that takes a commit reachable from a remote ref and makes it "no longer reachable" from that remote ref.

Another way to say it is, you cannot remove a commit from history while leaving the remaining commits undisturbed.  The commit after the removed one will have a new parent and a changed tree, making it a new commit (with a new ID).  And so, transitively, will every commit thereafter in the branch.

That being the case, if you're going to change the history there are lots of ways to do it.  The cherry-pick approach is ok.  You could do an interactive rebase (which might be simpler) to remove C, E, and G (or move them to the end and squash them if that's what you're after)... though this doesn't get them onto a separate branch without jumping through some extra hoops, so maybe not the best way if that's what you're after.